# Help in this proof

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-explanation

I need help to understand this proof:

**Theorem**

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic set and take $f\in k[X]$. Consider the open principal subset $X_f=\{x\in X;f(x)\neq 0\}$. Then $k[X_f]=k[X][1/f]=\left\{\frac{g}{f^m}; g\in k[X],m\ge 0\right\}$.

**PROOF**

Note that $X\subset \mathbb A^n$ is closed for some $n$. Let $G_1,\ldots,G_r\in k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ such that $I(X)=\langle G_1,\ldots,G_r\rangle$. Consider the affine closed subset $W\subset \mathbb A^{n+1}$ given by

$W=Z(G_1,\ldots,G_r,FT_{n+1}-1)$, where $F\in k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$ and the image of $F$ in the quotient $k[X]$ is $f$.

Then $W\cong X_f$ because there is a morphism:

$\varphi:\mathbb A^{n+1}\to \mathbb A^n$

$(x_1,\ldots,x_{n+1})\mapsto (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$

and  $\varphi(W)=X_f$.

The proof continues...

My question is quite simple: What does $k[X_f]=k[X][1/f]$ mean and why $\varphi(W)=X_f$?

I really need help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're notation means. What it's saying is that the regular functions on the set of points where $f$ does not vanish are merely quotients of functions, with the denominator a power of $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why is $\phi(W)=X_f$

Take and element in W say $(X_1,X_2,...X_n,X_{n+1})$ , i.e all the polynomials $G_1,G_2,...G_r,FT_{n+1}-1$ vanishes on this point. In particular $FT_{n+1}-1$ vanishes on $(X_1,X_2,...X_n)$ i.e. $F(X_1,X_2,...X_n).X_{n+1}-1=0$ .

Therefore, $F(X_1,X_2,...X_n)$ cannot be equal to zero (Note: it also says $F$ does not belong to $I(X)$.

$k[X]=k[T_1,T_2,...T_n]/I(X)$ and $f=F+I(X)$

Therefore, $f(X_1,X_2,...X_n)=F(X_1,X_2,...X_n)+I(X)$ is not zero

So, $\phi(X_1,X_2,...X_n,X_{n+1})=(X_1,X_2,...X_n)$ is an element of $X_f$

Threfore, $\phi(W)\subset X_f$

For the reverse inclusion. 
Take a point $(X_1,X_2,...X_n)\in X_f$

$\phi$  sends the point $(X_1,X_2,...X_n,1/F(X_1,X_2,...X_n))$ to $(X_1,X_2,...X_n)$

If we show $(X_1,X_2,...X_n,1/F(X_1,X_2,...X_n)) \in W $, we are done.

Now, As $G_i 's$ belong to $I(X)$ ,  $G_i(X_1,X_2,...X_n,F(X_1,X_2,...X_n,1/F(X_1,X_2,...X_n))=0$ (note:the n+1th component doesn't matter.)

And $ F(X_1,X_2,...X_n).(1/F(X_1,X_2,...X_n))-1=1-1=0$

So, $X_f\subset \phi(W)$

$\square$

Comment: Great answer, very detailed, thanks a lot!

Comment: @user42912: Bounty?

Comment: it's done! :)))

Answer (score 1):

So, $k[X_f]$ is the ring of all polynomials defined on the subset of $X$ where $f \neq 0$. Then, $k[X][1/f]$ is the ring of all polynomials in $1/f$ with coefficients in $k[X]$. See it as the ring $R[1/f]$, where $R = k[X]$. The content of the theorem is that these two rings are isomorphs.

I hope this helps enough for you to work through the proof.